# MAMP VirtualHost is not working on Windows

Tags: apache, mamp, virtualhost

I am trying to set VitualHost on MAMP Windows but it's not working. It's loading for 2-3 seconds and then showing `Can't access this website`.

Here is my configuration:

- httpd.conf

```
# Virtual hosts
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

- httpd-vhosts.conf

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>                                                                
    DocumentRoot C:\MAMP\htdocs\website
    ServerName project.local                                             
    ServerAlias www.project.local                                         

    <Directory "C:\MAMP\htdocs\website">                                          
        Allow from All                                                                  
        AllowOverride all                                                               
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymlinks                                                
    </Directory>                                                                      

    UseCanonicalName on                                                               
</VirtualHost>
```

Apache is on 80 port.

What's wrong here ?

Thanks !

Comment: check the error log, post them here.

Comment: There is no error log. I checked them :/ @PuneetChandhok

Comment: can you access http://localhost/website ?

Comment: Yep @PuneetChandhok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add following code in c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts

```
127.0.0.1 project.local
127.0.0.1 www.project.local
```

restart apache.